Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed Flutter
getting error Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1.
I tried many ways i set environment variables 17 java version and in my project gradle.properties also i added still iam getting this erroe
Can anyone help for the same

Can you please share the whole error
